# Embedded youtube video does not show in IE8 64bit

Tags: internet-explorer, flash

When embedding a youtube video on my website, i get a box with a red 'x' in Internet Explorer(64 bit)

Any ways to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Is there a 64bit version of Flash installed? Do the videos work on youtube? Have you embedded the right code?

Comment: Yes the video works on youtube.
I copy the embedded code youtube gives. It works fine on other browsers, just not IE 64bit.

Comment: Share the url, and we can test it for you... will tell you a lot more if others with IE can view it.  Maybe you @#$@# up the embed code?